# Does GCMNetworkManager OneOffTasks ever time out?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, android-jobscheduler

Lovely people!

My app is using GcmNetworkManager to schedule persistent jobs to log various messages to a backend service. Sometimes, the backend service is down, and the GcmNetworkManager automatically retries with backoff. However, I cannot really find information on for low long it retries, and/or the number of retries it makes. Does it just try forever? If not, is there a place where I can intercept the timeout and create an error log?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer you are looking for could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/util/BackOff). With this method below you can try to set how long it could take before it retries the operation:

> `nextBackOffMillis()` Gets the number of milliseconds to wait before
>   retrying the operation or `STOP` to indicate that no retries should be
>   made.